# AWS SNS access denied in AWS EKS no identity-based policy allows the action

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-ses

All SES related services using NestJS application in running on localhost, but whenever I deployed in AWS EKS as a `NodePort` service along with my other `NodePort` services in the same Kubernetes cluster, the SES access denied.

Although it seems everything running including the health-check of the service, I get the following errors in Postman for SES related command:

```
[
    "Failed to list email templates",
    {
        "name": "AccessDenied",
        "$fault": "client",
        "$metadata": {
            "httpStatusCode": 403,
            "requestId": "99werewr43-we4-435f-563b-e3252sdfsf",
            "attempts": 1,
            "totalRetryDelay": 0
        },
        "Type": "Sender",
        "Code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/eksctl-demo-application-nodegroup-NodeInstanceRole-1HO2384034FJ/i-e390239328wwrer is not authorized to perform: ses:ListTemplates because no identity-based policy allows the ses:ListTemplates action"
    }
]
```

My .env is as follows:

```
PORT=3003
SES_ACCESS_KEY=AWBFLDKLJFLKJKJDFDJKFJ
SES_SECRET_KEY=wqeriopisdfkjeroijfdsnlfierjiwejdfsdf/
SES_REGION=eu-west-2
SES_SENDER=example@gmail.com
```

SES client:

```
import { SESClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";

const SES_CONFIG = {
    credential: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.SES_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey:process.env.SES_SECRET_KEY,
    },
    region: process.env.SES_REGION,
};
// Create SES service object.
// const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: process.env.SES_REGION });
const sesClient = new SESClient( SES_CONFIG );

export { sesClient };
```

IAM user role with the associated Access Key and Secret above

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Kubernetes manifest for the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: demo-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-app
    spec: 
      containers:
        - name: demo-app 
          image: XXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/demo-app
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            - name: SES_ACCESS_KEY
              value: AWBFLDKLJFLKJKJDFDJKFJ
            - name: SES_SECRET_KEY
              value: 'wqeriopisdfkjeroijfdsnlfierjiwejdfsdf/'
            - name: SES_REGION
              value: eu-west-2
            - name: SES_SENDER
              value: example@gmail.com
---
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: demo-app-srv
  labels:
    app: demo-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: demo-app
  ports:
    - name: demo-app
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3003
      targetPort: 3003
```

I don't understand how can I give permission for the nodegroup mentioned in the error message:

```
"message": "User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/eksctl-demo-application-nodegroup-NodeInstanceRole-1HO2384034FJ/i-e390239328wwrer is not authorized to perform: ses:ListTemplates because no identity-based policy allows the ses:ListTemplates action"
```

Or is there anything I am missing. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue with "AWS SNS access denied in AWS EKS, no identity-based policy allows the action". The key point here is the use of the **Service Account**.

I have found that there are some third-party agents used on each node in Kubernetes cluster and allows cluster users to associate IAM roles to Pods.

They are:

1. [Kiam](https://github.com/uswitch/kiam) and
2. [kube2iam](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam)

But AWS official documentation says that AWS new feature eliminates the need for third-party solutions such as `kiam` or `kube2iam`. So, that's a good news.

Now, anyone can use the following AWS IAM roles for service accounts. Just follow all the step by step guideline to enable IAM roles for service accounts:

##### https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Answer (score 0):

Remeber you need to create a service account there link to your role my sample are in python but should be easy to translated to node

```
oidc_principal = iam.OpenIdConnectPrincipal(cluster.open_id_connect_provider)

role = iam.Role(
  self,
  id=role_name,
  role_name=role_name,
  assumed_by=oidc_principal,
)
```

that's code looks like missing in your stack and then you need to add the service account to your pod.